# Is there a historical source of all flights from a given airport?

Tags: general-aviation

I am trying to find delay data on all flights that departed from Malaga (AGP) airport on 29th September 2022. I have tried a trial of the highest tier subscription for Flight Radar 24. However, this is great for single route history, or short-term history for an airport (even on their highest tier, I could only go back a day or two for a whole airport), but I could not find a way to obtain the information I'm after.

I have looked at other sources such as Flightstats, Flightaware etc. (the first few on Google), but it is not clear whether they would provide this information. Does anyone have a suggestion on where I might find this? Ideally, the source would have a trial if the data is paid-for, as this is a one-time request only. I would consider paying if that's the only option.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of options here.

You could try the most direct route in contacting the airport directly (they have an email address and phone number) and ask.  Since this is only one day of data, you might get lucky (depending on how friendly they are) and get exactly what you're looking for.

https://www.airport-malaga.com/

The other option is a provider.  OAG offers historical data and have a trial available that might give you what you need.  The application form for this requests a company name, so this might not be applicable for individuals.

https://www.oag.com/historical-flight-data

As you've doubtless seen, historical data from FlightAware is expensive.  Obviously, historical data has commercial value in terms of analysing travel trends.